# Script for updating a stack or standalone via URL in LiveCode?

Tags: auto-update, livecode

I am looking for a routine to check for updates in a standalone, and the plugins I publish.

I have made some very simple scripts that check a file on my server, and alert the user if there is a new version available. But I'd like to include something more sophisticated, that can download and install an update, much like LC itself does, or Scripter's Scrapbook, for example.

This seems like one of those very common tasks that would be perfect for a library stack, or a script to copy and paste when developing.

There seems to be one in GLX, but I haven't been able to extract for use outside of GLX, at least not yet.

Does anyone know of such a library or script collection, commercial or not?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're already built what you need. If you're apple to check whether a file exists on your server and is more up-to-date all you need to do is download it. Something like the following should work.. though I've not tested it:

```
put URL "http://www.domain.com/myfile.jpg" into specialFolderPath("document") & "/myfile.jpg"
```

That would save the server file to the documents folder of the app. You can't write to the engine folder of you application.

Comment: Thanks! OK, I was kind of hoping for something a bit more sophisticated. I'll try combining what I have so far, and I don't find anything better I'll post it here for reference.